# Can't install iwlwifi driver in Crunchbang

Tags: drivers, wifi, crunchbang, wlan

I just installed Crunchbang 10 to my Laptop in dual boot with win7. My wlan card is a Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 2230. I saw I had no wifi, so I tried to install the driver from [here](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi%22here%22) by extracting them and typing:

```
sudo su
cp iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode /lib/firmware
```

After that, I rebooted and still had no Wifi. Why?

Comment: what does `dmesg` say? (search for something like `wl` in the output of dmesg)

Comment: Nothing like wl or wifi in output

Comment: have you check this ==> http://superuser.com/questions/564330/centrino-wireless-n-2230-on-gentoo  Also have you try to load the module with `modprobe iwlwifi`

Comment: @Kiwy modrporbe gives this output: `FATAL: Module iwlwifi not found.`
And ifconfig/iwconfig about wlan0 :
`wlan0     No such device`

Comment: As crunchbang is debian based have you try this: https://wiki.debian.org/iwlwifi

Comment: This doesn't work, too, maybe i'll switch to Crunchbang 11 or Linux Mint. But thanks for help anyway :D

Comment: It's a better idea to install drivers from your distribution's repos rather than the open ones on manufacturer's site